# Windows Phone and Windows 8.1 Mouse Press Tile Effects

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

On both windows and windows phone, the tiles on the start screen animate when the user clicks on them.

For example, if you're using windows 8 (or 8.1), open the start menu and click on a tile, you will see that the tile gets 'pushed back' depending on where the tile was clicked.

Is there a framework or dll where I can make use of these effects on my WPF controls?

Ideally I'd like to use it on custom tiles that I am creating. So when the user clicks on a tile, then the tile is animated accordingly, just like you'd expect like clicking on a tile on the windows start screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: https://mareinsula.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/wpf-tilt-effect-behavior/

Or you can use `TiltEffect` from WPToolkit, but there's no `PlaneProjection` in WPF, so you need to use `Planerator` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

[MahApps](http://mahapps.com/) and/or [M:UI](https://mui.codeplex.com/) will be useful for you.

Comment: Although useful, this does not satisfy my requirements. Thanks. :-)